# What is the difference between getContext('webgl') vs getContext('3d')?

Tags: html, canvas, webgl

I start learning WebGL, and because i have found some old tutorials, i dont know what is the right way in 2014?

I started the `<canvas>` (basic), and in tutorials they say something like:

> use `getContext('2d')` and if you want to use WebGL then you put `3d` instead of `2d`

But now that i am learning, i found tutorials talking about `getContext('webgl')` and not  `getContext('3d')` .

Have the syntaxe changed?

And there is [this](http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tutorials/f/is-there-a-3d-context-for-html5-canvas.htm) article saying that there is no real 3D, but they only using Ray Casting ?!

Comment: [MDN's reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) lists `webgl` and `experimental-webgl` as supported in *some* browsers.

Comment: so the `3d` word has been deprecated?

Comment: I don't know the full story, which is why I only added a comment, but that page doesn't mention a `'3d'` context ever having existed. Do you have an example where `'3d'` is being recommended? Perhaps the author was just guessing, since `'2d'` was initially the only option available.

Comment: the word `webgl` will make sense, since `webgl` is not only 3d

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Mozilla Developer Netowrk (MDN) Docs says this:

> getContext(in DOMString contextId)    RenderingContext    Returns a drawing context on the canvas, or null if the context ID is not supported. A drawing context lets you draw on the canvas. Calling getContext with "**2d**" returns a **CanvasRenderingContext2D** object, whereas calling it with "**experimental-webgl**" (or "**webgl**") returns a **WebGLRenderingContext** object. This context is only available on browsers that implement WebGL.

Results:

`| Context            | Chrome (webkit)          | Firefox (gekko)          |
| ------------------ | ------------------------ | ------------------------ |
| 2d                 | CanvasRenderingContext2D | CanvasRenderingContext2D |
| 3d                 | null                     | null                     |
| webgl              | WebGLRenderingContext    | WebGLRenderingContext    |
| experimental-webgl | WebGLRenderingContext    | null                     |`

I recommend reading up on the [webgl](http://get.webgl.org) wiki: http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/FAQ

Here is the full [What is the recommended way to initialize WebGL?](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_recommended_way_to_initialize_WebGL.3F) section:
(Though I suggest you read it right from the [wiki](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_recommended_way_to_initialize_WebGL.3F) in case it changes!)

---

## What is the recommended way to initialize WebGL?

It is recommended that you check for success or failure to initialize. If WebGL fails to initialize it is recommended you distinguish between failure because the browser doesn't support WebGL and failure for some other reason. If the browser does not support WebGL then present the user with a link to "http://get.webgl.org". If WebGL failed for some other reason present the user with a link to "http://get.webgl.org/troubleshooting/"

You can determine if the browser supports WebGL by checking for the existence of WebGLRenderingContext.

```
if (window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
  // browser supports WebGL
}
```

If the browser supports WebGL and canvas.getContext("webgl") returns null then WebGL failed for some reason other than user's browser (no GPU, out of memory, etc...)

```
  if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
    // the browser doesn't even know what WebGL is
    window.location = "http://get.webgl.org";
  } else {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("webgl");
    if (!ctx) {
      // browser supports WebGL but initialization failed.
      window.location = "http://get.webgl.org/troubleshooting";
    }
  }
```

Note: You MUST check that the browser supports WebGL to know that getting null from canvas.getContext() means
[There is a wrapper that will do all of this for you here.](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/demos/common/webgl-utils.js)

Example using the wrapper

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="localpath/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script>
  function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("c");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) {
      return;
    }
    ...
  }

  window.onload = init;
</script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ahhh! thank you! so definitly no `3d` and how about the article saying that the canvas fake the 3d to use only 2d, or is it because it is an old article?

Comment: @Abdelouahab, saying that 3d API is actually a 2d API is very old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135210/why-does-this-state-that-webgl-is-a-2d-api-not-a-3d-api It's just way of thinking, really. If some one asks you, canvas uses real 3d, it's not faking anything.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm ahhh thank you! now i update my information! internet contains lot of old tutorial, and there are outdated ones, so they need to be fixed! thank you again ^_^